# Staying with player on a moving object with physics and rigidbody doesn't work in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am trying to make character controller that can stand on a ground of a moving train that is using wheel coliders,rigidbody and simple script to go forward. I tryed a lots of tutorials where they make PlayerController as a child of a platform that is moving, but it is not working when I use scripts like :

```
{
    public GameObject Player;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject == Player)
        {
            Player.transform.parent = transform;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == Player)
        {
            Player.transform.parent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my "train" works. It is like a normal car, but it is sliding in a rail in which are 2 colliders under each wheel.

Train body picture in editor:
[image: Editor screenshot]

With that script my Player object goes into child of a train, but when the train is moving, player stays in one place anyways, or the physics goes crazy and it will clip to it, but it has different speed than train and its sliding to a random places. I think it is because script that I use is usually used with animated platforms and not platforms with physics. I am really new to unity and coding so I would be really happy if anyone could help me fix my problem.

Comment: You should use nested Rigidbodies. I don't know exactly how you move the player but you would need to take the "parent's"(do not really make it a parent) position/velocity into account: `player.MovePosition(parentPosition + ...)`

Comment: What are nested rigidbodyes? You meant that i should have rigidbody on some object and than player inside that object with controller on it? I tryed to find tutorials about MovePosition and parentPosition but i am not exactly sure how to use them and where to put them in the code. I am really new, so sorry for dumb questions.

Comment: Sorry autocorrect removed the **not** ^^ Ient you should **not** use nested Rigidbodies. By nested I mean you player probably has a Rigidbody and also as you described the train where you adding the player as child to is a Rigidbody as well. Such a construct doesn't work well in Unity

Answer (score 0):

If the player also has a rigidbody than that would explain the behaviour. You are using both physics (rigidbodies) and direct transform manipulation (due to the reparenting) to move the player. So maybe if you don't need to control the player during the ride you can turn off the rigidbody of the player and turn it on again when he/she leaves.

Comment: Problem is that i need to walk on the train when it is moving.

Comment: In that case check this answer out:
[link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/435891/independently-moving-rigidbody-inside-a-moving-rig.html)
(sorry my prev link was broken)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to highlight that having rigidbodies work with moving platforms can be extremely difficult, but one work around is to create isolated physics scenes to 'simulate' the train.  In the physics scene, the train is not moving so your simulated player or rigidbody can easily walk around on it without sliding/rolling off.  When the simulated player or rigidbody's position is updated, map this back to the real world with respect to the actual moving train.

Here is an example of this kind of system in motion:  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0_21aA4PxY&t=1s)

Here is a link to the documentation about physics scenes:  [unity multi-scene physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/physics-multi-scene.html)